# Tietze extension on C0 space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, operator-theory

I'm solving the following problem.

Let $X$ be a normal locally compact space and $F$ a closed subset of $X$. If $M = \{f \in C_0(X) : f = 0$ on $F \}$, then $C_0(X) / M$ and $C_0(F)$ are isometrically isomorphism.

Here,
$C_0(X) = \{f \in C(X) : \{x: \mid f(x) \mid \geq \epsilon\} \text{ is compact for any } \epsilon.\}$

My attempt:
As usual, $\phi : C_0(X) \longrightarrow C_0(F)$ by $\phi(f) = f\mid_F$.
Assuming $\phi$ is surjective, I solved every questions, but I don't know how to show the surjectivity. Of course it depends on Tietze extension theorem, but why there exist an extension which $is$ $in$ $C_0(X)$, vanishing at infinity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X^*$ be the one-point compactification of $X$ and $p$ be the point at infinity. Since $X^*$ is $T_4$, there exists a continuous function $g$ assuming values $0$ at $p$ and $1$ on $F$. Multiply the extension by $g$.